# How to deal with ui-sref in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, angular

**The Context:**

I'm using selenium in java to click on a link to navigate to the other page of the application.

**The Problem:**

The application is made in angular-js wherein I tried to click on the Link, but strange it logs out me directly.

But if I hit the same URL manually, after login it works fine.
I'm not sure Where I'm having a mistake here.

**The link I'm trying to click**

```
<a data-match-route="/about" ui-sref="about" href="#/about" class="active">About</a>
```

**tried and tested but not working Locators:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#/about']")

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='About']")
```

As soon as the URL is hit, it logs me out with a URL as

```
https: MY_HOST_URL/login.html#about
```

Not sure why and how login.html gets appended here.

I even tried to hit the full URL after login through the script but again it redirects to the same URL as

```
https://MY_HOST_URL/login.html#about
```

Comment: Have you tried with the class of the element? Can you share the code, please.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that another element is located and clicked, thus the log out. Try `cssSelector`:

```
By.cssSelector("a[ui-sref='about']")
```

I would suggest to test it in chrome devtools console like this:

```
$$("a[ui-sref="about]")
```

This is equivalent of `document.querySelectAll` so if it returns more then one element the locator is still not valid and you will have to be more specific. In such case posting more `html` code here can help.